# Using SendGrid From Command Line to Send Attachment

Tags: bash, sendgrid

I am trying to use sendgrid from a bash command line and need to have the email include an attachment.  I have the email going but can't figure out how to include the attachment.  I have tried &files as well as &attachment also have tried importing the attachment with << - none of these seem to be working

I have googled and while there is lots of information on using sendgrid there is virtually none on including attachments when using from the command line in a bash script.

Comment: Posting sample code will get a lot more answers, as a friendly suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem - the issue was when I added for the attachment I did not move the apostrophe to the end.  Below is my successful command line - Toast.txt is the file I am sending

`curl -d 'to=efultz@crunchtime.com &subject=Toast Employee Counts &from=efultz@crunchtime.com &files[Toast.txt]=@Toast.txt &text=Toast-Counts &api_user=****** &api_key=******' https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json`

Comment: Thanks, ```files[filename]=@localfile``` was the ticket. FYI you can also use "-F" to pass each argument separately: ```curl -Ss https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json -F to=recipient@example.com -F from=sender@example.com -F api_user=**** -F api_key=**** -F subject="My email with attachment" -F html="<b>Hello world</b>" -F files["myfilename.zip"]=@myfile.zip```